# Android - how to make failover delay between Wifi and Mobile Network shorter?

Tags: android, mobile, wifi, delay, failover

I've made an Android 4.0.3 application that is constantly communicating over the internet. Either by WiFi or Mobile Network, if the former is unavailable somehow. The problem is that if there's a need to switch from wifi to wifi, or just from wifi to mobile network, failover causes a 3-4 second offline period.

Is there a way to make the delay any shorter? Is it possible to somehow keep mobile network connected while wifi operates? I've read that Android is programmed to tear down any mobile connectivity when wifi starts. If this is true, every time wifi disconnects, Android has to start mobile network from sratch, and this takes time.

Thanks.